# Java removing and adding back MouseListener later

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, mouselistener

I have 4 `JLabel`s.

**upon first click:**

I changed the background color to red and removed `JLabel`'s `MouseListener` that I have clicked.

**upon second click:**

I change the background color to green, but the `JLabel` that I clicked previously shouldn't change from red to green since I had already removed the `MouseListener`.

**upon third click:**

I want to add back the `MouseListener` to the `JLabel` `MouseListener` that has been removed at first click and change the background color to black but I not sure how can I add back.

I tried to use `addMouseListener` method in my `addbackMouseListener(JLabel label)` but it's seems that I cannot pass in "this" in the parameter and I don't know what to pass in the parameter of the `addMouseListener`.

```
public void addbackMouseListener(JLabel label) {
    label.addMouseListener(this); <-- can't pass in this, what can I do?
}
```

---

Codes:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class rMouseListener extends JFrame {
    private JLabel[] jLabel = {new JLabel(), new JLabel(), new JLabel(), new JLabel()};;
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    private int clickCount = 0;
    private boolean mouseRemoved = false;

    public rMouseListener() {

        for(int i = 0; i< 4; i++) {
            jLabel[i].setText(i + " ");
            panel.add(jLabel[i]);
            jLabel[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    JLabel label =(JLabel) e.getSource();
                    clickCount++;

                    /*remove the mouseListener for the label that is clicked*/
                    if(clickCount == 1) {
                        label.setBackground(Color.red);
                        label.setOpaque(true);
                        label.removeMouseListener(this);
                        mouseRemoved = true;
                    }

                    /* to verify that the mouseListener for that label is removed after
                    first click.*/
                    else if(clickCount == 2) {
                        label.setBackground(Color.green);
                        label.setOpaque(true);
                    }

                    /*check if the mouseListener is removed.
                      add back the mouseListener to the one that is perviously
                      removed at clickCount = 1 if it's removed*/
                    else if(clickCount == 3) {
                        if(mouseRemoved) {
                            addbackMouseListener(label);
                            label.setBackground(Color.black);
                        }
                    }


                }
            });
        }
        add(panel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setSize(400,600);  
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addbackMouseListener(JLabel label) {
        label.addMouseListener(this); <-- can't pass in this, what can I do?
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new rMouseListener();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` refers to `rMouseListener`, which extends `JFrame`, it does not implement `MouseListener`

Your best bet might be to make your original `MouseAdapter` an inner class and create an instance of it when you create your class and simply add and remove it instead

For example...

```
public class rMouseListener extends JFrame {
    //...
    private MouseListener mouseListener;

    public rMouseListener() {

        mouseListener = new MouseHandler();
        for(int i = 0; i< 4; i++) {
            jLabel[i].setText(i + " ");
            panel.add(jLabel[i]);
            jLabel[i].addMouseListener(mouseListener);
        }
        //...
    }

    public void addbackMouseListener(JLabel label) {
        label.addMouseListener(mouseListener); 
    }

    //...

    public MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            JLabel label =(JLabel) e.getSource();
            clickCount++;

            /*remove the mouseListener for the label that is clicked*/
            if(clickCount == 1) {
                label.setBackground(Color.red);
                label.setOpaque(true);
                label.removeMouseListener(this);
                mouseRemoved = true;
            }

            /* to verify that the mouseListener for that label is removed after
            first click.*/
            else if(clickCount == 2) {
                label.setBackground(Color.green);
                label.setOpaque(true);
            }

            /*check if the mouseListener is removed.
              add back the mouseListener to the one that is perviously
              removed at clickCount = 1 if it's removed*/
            else if(clickCount == 3) {
                if(mouseRemoved) {
                    addbackMouseListener(label);
                    label.setBackground(Color.black);
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
addbackMouseListener(label);
```

with

```
label.addMouseListener(this);
```

You do not need `addBackMouseListener` method.

Hope this helps